# Using N-Tier EF: When Entity.IsValid = false, which Entity property is invalid?

Tags: entity-framework, validation, n-tier-architecture

We are using N-Tier Entity Framework version 1.9 with N-Tier Entity Framework VS2015.

When `Entity.IsValid = false`, how can I determine which property(s) is causing the Entity to be invalid?  I would expect to see something in the Entity.Errors list, but it is empty.  I know there is an `Entity.ValidateProperty()` method if I want to loop through them all, but I’d rather not have too.  Is there any other way?

@ChristofSenn I would appreciate your response. Thank you!

Comment: If you need to have specific user's support then you have to go the post of that user's and put this url there on the comment box.Otherwise the way you have mentioned above will not work hence he's not visible in this post.

Comment: Or contact via codeplex: https://ntieref.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Sampath Thanks for the tip.  I don't see a "comment box".  Could you please clarify.

Comment: Actually just `add a comment` on his post with this post's url. Then he'll be notified about this post Or do what  @SteveGreene said.